# Signal from Database

Tags: sql-server, database

I get a form filled from the user through browser..
I enter the values in a database
I want to call a script on the entry made in the database
(Do not want to call it from browser as browser has timeout issues. This script can take 10 hrs if it needs to)

Comment: I imagine you're looking for a trigger? What does this script do that it has to take so long?

Comment: yes. I am looking for a trigger. It does some heavy back-end cryptographic calculations based on the keys user gives

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you need a trigger:

A trigger is a special kind of stored procedure that automatically executes when an event occurs in the database server.

Example:

```
USE AdventureWorks2012;
GO
IF OBJECT_ID ('Sales.reminder2','TR') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TRIGGER Sales.reminder2;
GO
CREATE TRIGGER reminder2
ON Sales.Customer
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE 
AS
   EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
        @profile_name = 'AdventureWorks2012 Administrator',
        @recipients = 'danw@Adventure-Works.com',
        @body = 'Don''t forget to print a report for the sales force.',
        @subject = 'Reminder';
GO
```

[CREATE TRIGGER (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx)

Comment: perfect.. can we create triggers in MySQL db also?